# How to Change Font Size of Text Input in React Native when user starts typing?

Tags: react-native, components, font-size, textinput

so I am using a TextInput as a field for a user to fill out in a form. The placeholder for the form is quite long, so I gave it a small font size. When the user starts typing, I want the font size to increase. How do I do this?

I already tried:

```
_onChangeText(text) {
      this.setState({ fSize: text.length > 0 ? 20 : 10 });
    }
```

However, the first character entered is size 10, and all following are size 20. I tried changing the value of '0' but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example as Expo Snack: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/font-size-scaling-on-textinput

It's calculating changes when `onContentSizeChange` occurs (with every keystroke) and it compares the current content width to current fontSize and sets it smaller if content width > input field width.